# Logical mistake in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.x

The code is simple and you will be able to tell what it does once you see it.

```
n = int(input())
if(n%2!=0):
    print 'Weird'
elif(n%2==0):
    if(n>=2 & n<=5):
        print 'Not Weird'
    elif(n>=6 & n<=20):
        print 'Weird'
    elif(n>20):
        print 'Not Weird'
```

It works fine, but it shows errors for 2 cases only. When input is `18`, its says `'Not Weird'` whereas the output should be `'Weird'`. The same thing is happening when the input is `20`.
Its probably a silly mistake or something but I just can't seem to put my finger on it and I need someone to have a look at it.

Comment: You need to use `and` for the logical operator, `&` is a bitwise operator, with a different precedence which is causing your aberrant results (logical and bitwise boolean operators are equivalent with boolean arguments, but again, the precedance is what is messing you up. But you should still use the logical operators `and` and `or` and `not`). Also, saying "you will be able to tell what it does once you see it" is a good way to get downvoted. You should *always* properly specify your question.

Comment: unclear, what is the question?

Comment: Aside from the obvious mis-use of `&`, the `elif(n%2==0):` should be an `else:`, considering the `if` that precedes it (not that it would change anything).

Comment: "simple", but every other line is a branch statement.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, i'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, you don't need parentheses around the condition - they are only used for precedence, `if n % 2 != 0:` is OK.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please don't answer in comments, they can't be downvoted by the community, and can only be upvoted or flagged.  A chained comparison is better than changing the code to use `and` here.

Comment: You could combine all conditions to `"Weird" if n%2 != 0 or 6 <= n <=  20 else "Not Weird"`.

Comment: @wim a chained comparison is better, but that only applies to this particular case, when obviously, the OP's confusion is much more fundamental than that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition doesn't do what you think it does:

```
>>> n = 18
>>> n >= 2 & n <= 5
True
```

It is actually doing this:

```
>>> n >= (2 & n) <= 5
True
```

Proof:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('n >= 2 & n <= 5'), annotate_fields=False)
"Module([Expr(Compare(Name('n', Load()), [GtE(), LtE()], [BinOp(Num(2), BitAnd(), Name('n', Load())), Num(5)]))])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('n >= (2 & n) <= 5'), annotate_fields=False)
"Module([Expr(Compare(Name('n', Load()), [GtE(), LtE()], [BinOp(Num(2), BitAnd(), Name('n', Load())), Num(5)]))])"
```

docs reference on operator precedence is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Instead, use this:

```
2 <= n <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly modified your code getting rid of `&` . You can combine the range in the `if/elif` statement

```
n = int(input())
if(n%2!=0):
    print ('Weird')
elif(n%2==0):
    if(2<=n<=5):
        print ('Not Weird')
    elif(6<=n<=20):
        print ('Weird')
    elif(n>20):
        print ('Not Weird')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the operator `&` to `and`. `&` is a bitwise operator.